# get the list of application through UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uidocumentinteraction

I am using UIDocumentInteractionController to open the list of available pdf application in my device when i click on button but now i want to display setting table which will show the list of all the application and user will be directlly redirect to that applcation next time without displaying the actionsheet or any option
my cade is as below:

```
docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];

    docController.delegate = self;

    [docController retain];

    BOOL isValid = [docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't, it's not possible using the official SDK to:

- Get a list of apps that open a certain file
- Open a file with a certain app

One thing you can do is open a URL and the system will decide which app to open.